# Animation doesn't show up in render. Issue with image sequencer

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, image

I broke a glass in blender and initially I got the renderer animation in image sequence, later i did few changes in animation and now the renderer is not giving the animation in image sequence. Only the 1st frame is getting repeated. Kindly help solving the issue immediately.

Comment: Do you have any animation clips in the video editor? If you do, remove them, and try rendering again.

Comment: show us your blend file